# AngularJS $location.search() doesn't work - why? (no routing)

Tags: angularjs

**AngularJS $location.search() doesn't work - why? (no routing)**

What am I doing wrong, this is exactly as in docs.

here it is, all on this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: What happens if you use `this.$location.search().wonum`? What do you get from `console.log($location)` vs. `console.log(this.$location)`?

Comment: I get "undefined" for $location.search().wonum, but I get an object for $location and for $location.search()

Comment: And what about when using `this.`? You have it defined in your constructor as `private $location` which means technically it should be referenced as `this.$location`. This is TypeScript, no? You also mention in the question subject that you're not using routing - why is there a "-1" in the URL? Do you really have folder named "-1"?